# String to Field type - Accessing a field of an object with a local string variable

Tags: apex

I would like to access a field in my `Account` object with a locally constructed text variable (to be generic).
Account : Field -> `StatusS010__c`

In the program I recover and build: `"Status" + Company code + "__c"`

I have this error :

> Variable does not exist: societes

```
Map<ID,List<String>> mappingPCC = new Map<ID,List<String>>();

for(PropositionCommerciale__c PC: PropositionsCommercialesClients){
                    if(PC.Compte__c != null){
                        mappingPCC.get(PC.Compte__c).add((' Statut'+ (String)PC.Societe__r.CodeSociete__c + '__c' ));
                    }
                }

for(Account acc: Accounts){
            List<String> codesSocieteClient = mappingPCC.get(acc.Id);
            for(String societes : codesSocieteClient){
                acc.societes = 'Client';
            }

        }
```

Comment: this  line `acc.societes = 'Client';` . there is no `societes` field on `Account`

Comment: If the field `societes` is a custom field, it should be: `societes__c`

Comment: Of course when it is built I do: _'Statut'+(String)PC.Societe__r.CodeSociete__c+'__c'_ so i don't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to update your `Account` object by using dynamic field names.

If so, you should use the useful `put` method accessible on the generic [`SObject`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) class.

Here's the right code for your use case:

```
for(String societes : codesSocieteClient){
    acc.put(societes, 'Client');
}
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup Martin ! Je ne connaissais pas cette méthode. C'est bon pour moi ! Bonne journée

Comment: Oui elle est très utile ! De rien avec plaisir. Bonne journée.